# Have any full rank-and-file piece specifications ever been required in a masters level game of chess?

Tags: notation, famous-games, master-games

According to the rules of algebraic notation, in order for a move to be recorded with rank and file for both starting and ending square (eg, `Be5f4`), there would need to be, at a minimum:

- three pieces of the same type
- two of which share the same rank
- two of which share the same file
- all three of which can move to the target square

I believe this would require a minimum of either 1 knight promotion, 2 queen promotions, or 2 bishop promotions.

Has such a move ever been recorded in a masters level chess game?

Comment: https://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/records/records.htm is the first place to check, but not of the games there (nor the forged Alekhine-Grigoriev 5 queens game) contains a move that fits.

Comment: I do have a proof game composition that contains this. It was constructed  a couple of years ago to highlight the fact that the PDB problem database animation engine does not support the standard notation for this kind of move. It’s completely artificial but it’s fun to find the unique solution. I can post it as an answer here if the question is broadened

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think we need that. I was also able to construct a game in which Be4f5# was the winning move. Curious what you mean about "the unique solution" though?

Comment: I mean that it’s a “unique proof game” puzzle. There is only one game which leads to the final position in the required number of moves

Comment: OIC - there is not only one possible position that meets the requirements, but for the given position, there is only one possible game that gets there.